# Is there is the limit of Socket io concurrnet connection(Node js) per a port?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, max

I'm making socket io server with node js.
One day, I tested my socket io application(used as a chat server) via 'socket-stress-test'. just tested one host with one port

my server OS ulimit setting is like below..
* hard nofile 600000
* soft nofile 600000

First, I changed my ulimit value 600000 -> 800, and then the result said that max number of socket.io concurrent connection is 787(this is good result I expected.)

But the problem is occured my ulimt value is 600000, the number of socket io concurrent connection is almost 1400...

Is there is the limit of max connection per one port?

Comment: Where does the 1400 number come from?  While there may be a limit per port, it's way, way, way higher than 1400 so that's not what you're hitting.  There are special configurations that can get hundreds of thousands of concurrent sockets.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket-stress-test   
My computer connect to test socket io server 1400 times after 1400 connection disconnect occurs